# Laravel5.2 Unwanted VerifyCsrfToken

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, csrf, middleware

i set up fresh L5.2 and my route files after changes looks like that:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' =>'api', 'prefix' => '/api/v1'], function () {
    Route::post('/api/v1/login', 'Api\V1\Auth\AuthController@postLogin');

});
```

When i go to postman and make POST: http://kumarajiva.dev/api/v1/login I get: `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67`

But me kernel file looks like that:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

I don't change anything. Route 'login' is in 'api' middelware group (not 'web' where is VerifyCsrfToken), but surprisingly I get above error. So I wonder - wtf? Howi it works? Do 'web' middelware group is allways executed (for each request)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it looks as if all routes are wrapped into the 'web' group.

Within `RouteServiceProvider` there is this function.

```
    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
        ], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
```

If you want a specific uri to not check for the CSRF Token, go to `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` and add the uri to the `$except` array.

You can also use the CLI and `php artisan route:list` to see what routes are in behind what middleware.

Comment: Yes you have right, i run `php artisan route:list` and all my routes have 'web' middelware. It is very counterintuitive... thank U for your answer.

Comment: After I remove `'middleware' => 'web'` from function `RouteServiceProvider @mapWebRoutes` it WORKS :) which I see using `php artisan route:list`